# In an Android state-list drawable, state_focused is ignored

Tags: android, drawable, tabwidget

My Android app, which uses a TabActivity to display its contents, has 4 tabs which all use a state-list drawable for the icon. They all have the same structure, just with different images:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_options_dark" android:state_selected="true" android:state_focused="false" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_options_white" />
</selector>`
```

However, when selecting tabs with the trackball on my HTC Desire (green highlight), the dark image is used instead of the light one. As soon as a tab is actually selected, it does become white. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have different items for different states. Combining several states in one item (as you did) is definitely wrong. Your XML can look like this:

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_options_dark"
        android:state_selected="true" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_options_light"
        android:state_focused="true" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_options_white" />
</selector>
```

When it comes to drawing your drawable its state is firstly checked. If it is selected the first item will be used and that's it - no focused check will be performed (Android finds only **first** - not **"most relevant"** - state). But if it is not selected, the check for the focused state will be performed.